# How do I refresh a python file every minute?

Tags: python

I am trying to refresh a python file every minute, as I am trying to create graphs and save images of it every minute. Running a function repeatedly doesn't work because all it does is plot the graph again, without using the live data from the CSV file which includes the data I use to plot the graph. Is there any way to refresh the file repeatedly?

I have already tried most of the code I found on stack overflow.

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc): 
    print "Doing stuff..."
    # do your stuff
    s.enter(60, 1, do_something, (sc,))

s.enter(60, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

Comment: You want to check a csv file every minute?

Comment: I want to rerun it every minute.

Comment: do you read data again every minut ? You have to read data again every minut.

Comment: I read the data every minute. It's just that the graph doesn't automatically update. I need it to update every minute.

Comment: where do you update graph ? on some web page ? then you have to use HTML or JavaScript code to refresh web page.

Comment: You could try a while loop around all your code and sleep for 60 seconds at the end of the loop

Comment: I tried that, it still didn't refresh the graph, it only recreated the same graph using the old data, not the updated data.

Comment: *Running a function repeatedly doesn't work because all it does is plot the graph again, without using the live data from the CSV file which includes the data I use to plot the graph*  Well, it would help if you could provide a [MCVE]. What you're describing here seems to indicate a failure in the way you're reading the CSV and/or plotting the graph.

Comment: maybe you don't create csv with new data or you create it id different place and code always use csv with old data.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to do this from a shell rather than Python.

`while true; do python my_script.py; sleep 60; done`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rerun your program every minute, you can wrap your program into a function, and then call that function every 60 sec. Something like:

```
import time
while True:
    your_function()
    time.sleep(60) #1 minute
```